# why the angle is not regulary

Tags: java, android, math

I have a mathematically problem.
I'm workin on a tank game in android studios and want to calculate the trajectory for the shot.
for this i implement a little application where i trie every angel from 0 to 360 to look in which directory the shot goes. so i go through the 360 angles and place each of them with the same start speed and at the same time and add a texview with the angle as content on the layout with the calculated x and y Posistion. i expected a circle from 1 to 360. but the angle ar not regulary. here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RelativeLayout layout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = findViewById(R.id.layout);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        shot( );
    }

    public void shot() {

            for(int winkel = 0;angle<360;winkel++) {
                TextView textView = new TextView(this);
                textView.setText(""+angle);
                textView.setTextSize(10);
                int i = 10;
                int power = 50;
                System.out.println(angle);
                textView.setX((float) (500+(power * Math.cos(angle) * i)));
                textView.setY(((float) (0-((power * Math.sin(angle) * i) - (0.5 * 9.81 * Math.pow(i, 2))))));
                //System.out.println((float) ((((power * Math.sin(angle) * i) - (0.5 * 9.81 * Math.pow(i, 2))))));
                layout.addView(textView);

            }

    }
}
```

the power represents the start speed and i the time where i stop the shot.
Here are the two formulas to calcualte the x/y-Position

- SX-direction = power · cos(angle) · i
- SY-direction = power ·    sin(angle) · i + 0,5 · -g · i2

the ouput should be a circle that consists of numbers which went from 0 to 360 but the nubers are completle random
why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Math functions always work in radian, not degrees. That means you have to convert you angles before calling `Math.cos` and `Math.sin`:

```
Math.cos(angle / 180 * Math.PI)
Math.sin(angle / 180 * Math.PI)
```

They look randomly because with the 360 radian you are currently using you have made about 60 circles and your numbers interleave on these 60 rotations.